# Analytics properties for debug and release in android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

There is some way to have two different properties in Firebase/Analytics, one for debug version and other for release version?

I've been searching and I can not find the way.

Thank you friends!

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Comment: Thanks It's just what I was looking for!